# 'Featured meta post' is confusing in app feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

In the mobile app feed, the Android one specifically, I'll see 'Featured meta post' show up once in a while. When I see that wording with the megaphone icon, I think that it's a post with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and it's showing up under the 'Featured on Meta' headline on the desktop sidebar. I do notice that the tags are shown below the feature meta post title and I just assume [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) isn't displayed since the featured nature of the post has already been established. When I visit the post, I'm surprised to find out it's not [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). It's more like the 'Hot Meta Posts' area of the desktop sidebar.

Can the headline be changed from 'Featured meta post' to something more like the site, say 'Hot Meta post' or 'Trending Meta post'?

[image: screenshot showing the featured meta post in feed]

<sup>App version 1.0.59</sup>